# If an instance is shown in both autowired and bean, which one Spring will use

Tags: java, spring

Originally, there was a `service` instance to access the database and now we want to add a readonly instance. So I add the `serviceReadonly` in my configuration.

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean Service service() {...};
    @Bean Service serviceReadonly() {...};
    @Bean Proxy proxy() {return new Proxy(serviceReadonly())}; // replace the original Proxy(service())
}
```

But, the `service` is also autowired to `Proxy`

```java
@Component
public class Proxy {
    @Autowired
    public Proxy(Service service) {this.service = service;}
}
```

I am confused which `Service` is injected in my API? service or serviceReadonly?

```java
@Component
public class API {
    @Autowired
    public API(Proxy proxy) {this.proxy = proxy;}
}
```

The `Proxy` and `API` classes are in another shared library and avoiding change to the library is preferred. Also, the `service` is autowired to other components.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I made a PoC project and it seems like the answer is `serviceReadonly`. I need to inspect more to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: That is the answer, proxy is injected, which you have explicitly told to use `serviceReadonly`, not sure why the answers think differently. As an aside if you have a single constructor you don't need the `@Autowired` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `@Bean Service service()`

Explanation: Excerpt from the Spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire)

> Autowiring by property name. Spring looks for a bean with the same
>   name as the property that needs to be autowired. For example, if a
>   bean definition is set to autowire by name, and it contains a master
>   property (that is, it has a setMaster(..) method), Spring looks for a
>   bean definition named master, and uses it to set the property.

Comment: Nope, would be the readonly one. Since `@Bean Proxy proxy() `, creates the proxy with the readonly one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it will be `@Bean Service service()` because the Spring would find the bean with same name as the property i.e. `Service` as defined in official Spring [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-autowire). 
You may also need to look into [@Qualifier annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation). It is because if there is not exactly one bean of the constructor argument type in the container, a fatal error is raised, as mentioned in Spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire). Have you checked if you receive this error of NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException? In that case you can use @Qualifer annotation to specify the bean you want.

Comment: Good point. We use `@ComponentScan` to avoid the NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException